# PyTorch Neural Net not learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch and I'm trying to build a simple neural net for classification. The problem is the network doesn't learn at all. I tried various learning rate ranging from 0.3 to 1e-8 and I also tried training it for a longer duration. My data is small with only 120 training examples and the batch size is 16. Here is the code

Define network

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(4999, 1000),
                  nn.ReLU(),
                  nn.Linear(1000,200),
                  nn.ReLU(),
                  nn.Linear(200,1),
                  nn.Sigmoid())
```

Loss and optimizer

```
import torch.optim as optim

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = nn.BCELoss(reduction="mean")
```

Training

```
num_epochs = 100
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  cumulative_loss = 0
  for i, data in enumerate(batch_gen(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16)):
    inputs, labels = data
    inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs).float()
    labels = torch.from_numpy(labels).float()

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    cumulative_loss += loss.item()

    if i%5 == 0 and i != 0:
      print(f"epoch {epoch} batch {i} => Loss: {cumulative_loss/5}")
  


print("Finished Training!!")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please, define "doesn't learn at all".

Comment: The cost doesn't decrease. It prints out a value close to 0.85. I'll paste the output below:
epoch 0 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8719038724899292
epoch 1 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8388367891311646
epoch 2 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8633842468261719
epoch 3 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8806787371635437
epoch 4 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8124411225318908
epoch 5 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8659050703048706
epoch 6 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8588926792144775
epoch 7 batch 5 => Loss: 0.840653908252716
epoch 8 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8567716121673584
epoch 9 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8559732794761657
epoch 10 batch 5 => Loss: 0.8497568011283875

Answer (score 0):

The reason your loss doesn't seem to decrease every epoch is because you're not printing it every epoch. You're actually printing it every 5th batch. And the loss does not decrease a lot per batch.

Try the following. Here, loss every epoch will be printed.

```
num_epochs = 100
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  cumulative_loss = 0
  for i, data in enumerate(batch_gen(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16)):
    inputs, labels = data
    inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs).float()
    labels = torch.from_numpy(labels).float()

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    cumulative_loss += loss.item()

  print(f"epoch {epoch} => Loss: {cumulative_loss}")

print("Finished Training!!")
```

One reason that your loss doesn't decrease could be because your neural-net isn't deep enough to learn anything. So, trying add more layers.

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(4999, 3000),
                  nn.ReLU(),
                  nn.Linear(3000,200),
                  nn.ReLU(),
                  nn.Linear(2000,1000),
                  nn.ReLU(),
                  nn.Linear(500,250),
                  nn.ReLU(),
                  nn.Linear(250,1),
                  nn.Sigmoid())
```

Also, I just noticed you're passing data that has very high dimensionality. You have 4999 features/columns and only 120 training examples/rows. Converging a model with so less data is next to impossible (considering you have very high dimensional data).

I'd suggest you try finding more rows or perform dimensionality reduction on your input data (like PCA) to reduce the feature space (to maybe 50/100 or lesser features) and then try again. Chances are that your model still won't converge but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried printing it out every epoch as you suggested and it still remains constant. Also, I believe cost should decrease even if I was printing every 5th batch since by then the SGD would have taken 5 steps. And I added a few more layers and it still doesn't work. I'm guessing maybe the parameter initialization is not proper. Any chance you know how Pytorch initializes parameters? Ideally I want a He initialization and not Xavier.

Comment: Default model initialization is not Xavier. Try stacking a few more layers to your model. Try to overfit on this data. Once you do that, then start removing elements that cause overfitting one-by-one until you get a good performance. I've added an edit to the answer, check it out.